# Using socket.io in multi files

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using Node.js Express with socket.io.

```
//app.js
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server,{'log level': 1});
```

and if I want to do "io.sockets.emit" only for people watching index page which is provided by index.js how can I call "io.sockets.emit" in index.js other than using "require" for app.js(main file)?

I've googled about it though I couldn't find any sample source code which use socket.io in multiple files.

Comment: Did you try out the example bellow, was this what you where searching for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your backend is separated in several module files like index.js, it's possible to pass variables to modules upon initialization.

Try importing index.js after initializing socket.io, and pass `io` to the index.js module being imported:

```
require('./index.js')(io);
```

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059246/how-to-include-route-handlers-in-multiple-files-in-express).