# What is the difference between "express.Router" and routing using "app.get"?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have an app with following code for routing:

```
var router = express.Router(); 
router.post('/routepath', function(req, res) {});
```

Now I have to put routing code in different files so I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059246/how-to-include-route-handlers-in-multiple-files-in-express) approach, but it is **not** working perhaps because instead of `express.Router()` it uses:

```
app.post("/routepath", function (req, res) {});
```

How can I put routing in different files using `express.Router()`?

Why `app.get`, `app.post`, `app.delete`, etc, are not working in `app.js` after using `express.Router()` in them?

Comment: Asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305120/differences-between-express-router-and-app-get

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi this one is older than your linked question

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
// myroutes.js
var router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello from the custom router!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

---

```
// main.js
var app = require('express')();

app.use('/routepath', require('./myroutes'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello from the root path!');
});
```

Here, *`app.use()` is mounting the `Router` instance at `/routepath`*, so that any routes added to the `Router` instance will be relative to `/routepath`.

Comment: works great for res.send thanks
but functions declared in main.js are not accessible for routes in myroutes.js

Comment: If you have shared code like that, then put that code in a separate file/module (e.g. common.js) and simply require() them in your main.js and myroutes.js (and wherever else).

Comment: Express 4.0 does not have `app.router`

Comment: @RavishankarRajendran `require('express').Router()` != `app.router`

Comment: @RavishankarRajendran Express 4 certainly [does have `require('express').Router`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router).

Comment: _You no longer need to load app.router. It is not a valid Express 4 app object, so remove `app.use(app.router);`_. This text is from [Express Site](http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html). Also I think the routing middleware does not come with Express anymore by default. But one can install it manually. For these reasons I would stop using `router` and use `app.[method]`

Comment: @RavishankarRajendran `app.router` has nothing to do with `require('express').Router` (which is an Express 4 thing). They are separate things. Mounting separate routers allows you to organize your routes better. A simple example of this is shown in my answer.

Comment: What is app.router?