# Difference Between app.use() and router.use() in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I was just reading the documentation on express and found these two terms, `app.use();` and `router.use();`

I know `app.use();` is used in node for **Mounting a middleware** at a path, and we often use it in most of the node apps. but what is `router.use();` are they both same? if not, whats the difference ?

I read about router [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#router). I also found similar questions on SO [What is the difference between "express.Router" and routing using "app.get"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607058/what-is-the-difference-between-express-router-and-routing-using-app-get)
 and [Difference between app.all('*') and app.use('/')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125997/difference-between-app-all-and-app-use), but they do not really answer my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

`router.get` is only for defining subpaths. Consider this example:

```
var router = express.Router();

app.use('/first', router); // Mount the router as middleware at path /first

router.get('/sud', smaller);

router.get('/user', bigger);
```

- If you open **/first/sud**, then the `smaller` function will get called.
- If you open **/first/user**, then the `bigger` function will get called.

In short, `app.use('/first', router)` mounts the middleware at path **/first**, then `router.get` sets the subpath accordingly.

---

But if we instead use the following:

```
app.use('/first', fun);

app.get('/sud', bigger);

app.get('/user', smaller);
```

- If you open **/first** in your browser, `fun` will get called,
- For **/sud**, `bigger` will get called
- For **/user**, `smaller` will get called

But remember for **/first/sud**, no function will get called.

This link may also help: http://expressjs.com/api.html#router

Comment: But why use router when you can go app.use('/first/sud', smaller); and app.use('/first/user',bigger)?  I mean did they create router so we don't have to type extra stuff in the first parameter?

Comment: nice question look i dont know it correctly but i think this is the thing actually routing was made to dicrecting on urls where app.use is made for middleware now you can useapp.use('/first/sud', smaller); but suppose in your app you have many routes with starting as /first/second/third/fourth now would you make every route here /first/second/third/fourth/x, no you will use router here remember both works great but router was made just for these urls purposes

Comment: So, it means we can't do nesting using `router`. We can do only by `app`. Is that correct?

Comment: Why does the OP ask regarding `router.use` but this answer responds referring to `router.get`?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, not sure why so many upvotes

Comment: Why is this answer even marked as correct? The one below is not only correct but also like 7 months older... It is just confusing to people who come here

Answer (score 97):

`router.use();` mounts middleware for the routes served by the specific router, `app.use();` mounts middleware for all routes of the app (or those matching the routes specified if you use `app.use('/ANYROUTESHERE', yourMiddleware());`).

Example use case could be an app with one router with standard routes and one router that handles api routes, which need a valid user.

You would then mount the authentication middleware for the api router only with `router.use(yourAuthMiddleware());`.

If you would have an app though that requires a valid user for all routes, mount the middleware for the app with `app.use(yourAuthMiddleware());`

Comment: Can I create a new router and then `use` it in another router? Like `router1.use('/path', router2);`

Comment: This answer is clear and should be the accepted answer. Router is often misused where app would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

app.use() used to Mounts the middleware function or functions at the specified path,the middleware function is executed when the base of the requested path matches path.

router.use() is used to middleware function or functions, The defaults mount path to “/”.

**But in 
app.use() you will have to give a specified path like that:**

```
 var adsRouter = require('./adsRouter.js');
    app.use('/ads', adsRouter);
```

or

```
app.use('/ads', function(req, res, next) {

  // write your callback code here.

    });
```

**But while using router.use() you can give only middleware, like this:**

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('%s %s %s', req.method, req.url, req.path);
  next();
});
```

or

```
router.use('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  // write your callback code here.
  next();
});
```

or

```
//in router.js

router.use('/admin', authUtil.verifySessionId, authUtil.verifyLisencee);
router.post('/admin', controllerIndex.ads.adListingAdmin);
```

**In the above code when the end point is '/admin' then first it will call the authUtil.verifySessionId and authUtil.verifyLisencee then it will execute next line with 'admin' end point and according to  controllerIndex.ads.adListingAdmin method.**

Comment: A path does not need to be provided to `app.use` if you'd like to execute the function for every request made to the app.

Comment: @shubham You explained very well and it was very helpful to me. In case of router with middleware we also can merge it into single line like 

router.delete("/:id/delete", middleware.checkToken, userController.deleteUser)

Answer (score 2):

When looking at the express js docs for Routing (https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router):

> Use the express.Router class to create modular, mountable route handlers. A Router instance is a complete middleware and routing system; for this reason, it is often referred to as a “mini-app”.

A `Router` created with `express.Router()` is no different than an `app` created with `express()` in terms of functionality; it's like a logical grouping of routes/handlers/services/databases/etc. The biggest difference is the scope that it affects. A router just affects its own scope while the app is like the master/global scope for your web/app server. You could have many routers or "apps" running on one main app/web server instance. This is why you could listen to requests on an app instance via `app.listen(80)` but not on a router.

Answer (score 1):

`app.use(middleware)`: application-level middleware.

`router.use(middleware)`: router-level middleware.

("middleware" refers to methods/functions/operations that are called between processing the request and sending the response.)

See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html for a comparison of different types of middleware used in an Express app.