# Express bodyparser isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

To set up my bodyparser I use the following code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
```

Now if I have the following POST route in my express router:

```
var router = require('express').Router();

router.post('/sendadvertisement', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
});
```

The result is `[Object: null prototype] {advertisement: 'test'}`
-> My `req.body` isn't empty because it's in json format in my console output.

I don't really understand how this result can happen because I defined that the body should be in json format. 
I also tried it with `app.use(express.json())`, doesn't work either.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts

Comment: @S.Kuiter Already read this article.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [req.body empty on posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts)

Answer (score -1):

I replaced router with app and everything worked fine.

Router.get/post etc is only for defining sub routes after after you mounted a middelware function like `app.use('route')` that handels the Route. If you want to use the router you should mount the route using `app.use(...)` and then declare the post using `router.post(...)`

Also See: [Difference Between app.use() and router.use() in Express](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27227650/9881295)

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.post('/sendadvertisement', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
});
app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 8000!')
});
```

Comment: That's not a solution, it just tells us that it has something to do with the router

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score -1):

If you are using express then you can use this code to set your body parser.

```
app.use(express.json( {extended:false} ));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

This is also giving error, page is scrolling after submission.