# expressjs error middleware not firing in router (grouping error middleware)

Tags: express

I wanted to group all my functions that handle errors. I thought of using a router for this (like normal middleware functions). But when using a router for my middleware error function it never fires. Using the error middleware directly works without problems. This is probably because router is only responsible for [subpaths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227650/difference-between-app-use-and-router-use-in-express). But how can I then group my error handlers? I'd like to avoid having  to `use` all of them in my index.js individually. How can I group them on a "global" level?

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('ok'))


const errRouter = express.Router();
errRouter.use(jsonParseError)

function jsonParseError(err, req, res, next) {
    return (err instanceof SyntaxError && err.status === 400 && 'body' in err) ?
        res.sendStatus(400) :
        next();
}

app.use(errRouter)
// app.use(jsonParseError)

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error handling middleware in Express.js must be defined with four arguments `(err, req, res, next)` to be recognized as an error-handling middleware. Express determines the type of middleware based on the number of arguments the function takes. If you try to use these within a router, they are expected to handle errors that occur in the context of that router only which means errors that happen during the processing of paths that the router is handling.

So, instead of using a router, you can group your error handling middleware into a separate module and then require that module in your main js file.

Try following:

**errorHandlers.js**

```
function jsonParseError(err, req, res, next) {
    return (err instanceof SyntaxError && err.status === 400 && 'body' in err) ?
        res.sendStatus(400) :
        next();
}

function genericErrorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send('Error occurred!');
}

module.exports = {
    jsonParseError,
    genericErrorHandler
};
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { jsonParseError, genericErrorHandler } = require('./errorHandlers');

app.use(express.json());
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('ok'));

app.use(jsonParseError);
app.use(genericErrorHandler);

app.listen(3000);
```

**Update**: you may also want to avoid individually listing each error handler when importing them. If so, you can structure your error handlers into an array and then spread them into `app.use` call.

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const errorHandlers = require('./errorHandlers');

app.use(express.json());
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('ok'));

const errorHandlerArray = Object.values(errorHandlers);    
app.use(...errorHandlerArray);

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Just as a side node, why do you return on sendStatus but not on next?

Comment: you mean, in the `jsonParseError()`? or `genericErrorHandler()`?

Comment: in jsonParseError

Comment: Well, if there's code that could execute after `next(err);` that you wish to avoid, then you'd use `return next(err);`. Otherwise, you're good.

Comment: Actually, your original code block may be more efficient. I'll update my answer with your code. `return (err instanceof SyntaxError && err.status === 400 && 'body' in err) ? res.sendStatus(400) : next();`