# app.post is not a function express node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I had all my routes in server.js but I wanted to make it modular and put into a folder called routes. I created a file called apis.js in routes folder but as I did that I get `TypeError: app.post is not a function`

server.js:

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencode = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true});

app.use(express.static('public'));

var apis = require('./routes/apis');
app.use('/', apis);

module.exports = app;
```

apis.js:

```
  module.exports = function(app){

  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('OK');
  });

  app.post('/idea', function(req, res) {
  ...
  });

};
```

Also, having `module.exports = app` in server.js is important as I have tests running and I want a instance of app everytime.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Better approach :-

server.js

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencode = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true});

app.use(express.static('public'));

var apis = require('./routes/apis');
app.use('/', apis);

module.exports = app;
```

apis.js :-

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.post('/url',function(req,res,next){
 //your code 
})

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in your express app into your `apis` module so it can attach the routes to your app. If you want to use `app.use` to put your routes in a different root path, you can create another express router, and attach your routes to that, then `app.use` that router:

server.js:

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencode = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true});

app.use(express.static('public'));
var apis = express.Router();

require('./routes/apis')(apis);

app.use('/', apis);
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: I cant do app.use with this for /

Comment: You can create another router using `express.Router()` if you want to do `app.use` to mount it in a different place, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple different methods for connecting your app to your routes, and it looks to me like you are mixing them together, resulting in your error.

The fix already mentioned...

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.post('/url',function(req,res,next){
 //your code 
})

module.exports = router
```

...works with the way you currently have your `server.js` file set up.

Another method that doesn't require you to modify your `apis.js` file is to require it in `server.js` using

```
require("./routes/apis.js")(app);
```

instead of

```
var apis = require('./routes/apis');
app.use('/', apis);
```

This ensures that the variable app is passed into the function in `apis.js`

The first version is recommended, but hopefully this explains why you are getting confused between the two, i.e. because the second is an alternate version.

See [Differences between express.Router and app.get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305120/differences-between-express-router-and-app-get) for more information on why the router version is recommended.