# Difference between app.get() or router.get() - ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, express

What is the difference between:

```
var express = new express();
var app = new express();

app.get("/", function() {

.....
})
```

And:

```
var express = new express();
var router= express.Router();

    router.get("/", function() {

    .....
    })
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305120/differences-between-express-router-and-app-getm
please check this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences between express.Router and app.get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305120/differences-between-express-router-and-app-get)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`app.get` can be used to create routes for your application at the top level.

From the documentation about [`express.Router`](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router)

> Use the express.Router class to create modular, mountable route handlers. A Router instance is a complete middleware and routing system; for this reason, it is often referred to as a “mini-app”.

A router needs to be mounted to an app:

```
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (res, req) => res.end());
router.post("/", (res, req) => res.end());

app.use("/empty", router);
```

This allows you to more easily encapsulate the functionality of several routes into an app which will be namespaced under a particular route.

Comment: Ahh this is so helpful.

Answer (score 5):

> When express() is called in app.js, an app object is returned. Think of an app object as an Express application.
>
> When express.Router() is called, a slightly different "mini app" is
>   returned. The idea behind the "mini app" is that different routes in
>   your app can become quite complicated, and you'd benefit from moving
>   that logic into a separate file.

Check this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305120/differences-between-express-router-and-app-get) for details.