# Routing with Express when using React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, express

I want to set the routes for my web app using Express, and I'm also using React to handle the front end. The problem is that I don't understand how to route things properly when using React components.

I have in my index.html:

```
<script> document.getElementById("input").onchange = function() {  ...  } </script>
```

And my App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return ( <div><input id="input" /></div> );
    }

}
```

And router.js:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/index.html'))
})
app.use(express.static('static'));
app.listen(3001, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3001!')
})
```

And static/index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

The problem is that I'm getting "Cannot set property 'onchange' of null". Obviously the App object was not rendered, but I don't understand why. How can I make this work?

Comment: can wrap your script code  inside a function passed to `window.onload`

Comment: After the page loads, what does `document.getElementById("input")` return in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the express router

[Differences between express.Router and app.get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305120/differences-between-express-router-and-app-get)

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname), '../public/index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try two things:

1. Remove the `document.getElementById("input").onchange` inside of the `script` tag and instead put `console.log('I am running the script tag')`
2. Put a `console.log('I am rendering the App via react' inside of your`render`method, right above`return`.

I am imagining that the `script` tag gets "evaluated" before `react` has done anything with the DOM, causing `document.getElementById` to not return anything, hence your `null`.

If this is true, you will see your `I am running the script tag` before your see `I am rendering the App`.