# Cannot GET /foo when using express.Router()

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out why the routing doesn't work if I use `expressjs`, I have this code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.get('/foo', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World.')
});
```

the code above works well, but if I replace the route with this:

```
router.get('/foo', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('This is api.')
});
```

I get:

> Cannot GET /foo when using express.Router()

Comment: Is this code in your root server file (app.js / index.js) or in another file?

Comment: @sfarzoso when you use the router you need to make sure you also do `app.use(router)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the following:
`app.use(router);`
Towards the bottom of your code. You'll also need
`app.listen(3000);`
Or whatever port you want to run your application on.

Full example:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/foo', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('This is api.')
});

app.use(router);
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: just a question: is better use router or app with post, get ...?

Comment: @sfarzoso Depends on how complicated your app is. Maybe check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305120/differences-between-express-router-and-app-get to get some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure each router properly in order to use it in Express.

In your root server file (`index.js`/`app.js`) you need to register the router with the app. For example:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const fooRouter = require("./routes/foo");
app.use("/foo", fooRouter);
```

Then in `routes/foo.js` you can use your code as before ("but note that route paths will be relative to `"/foo"` a this point), but you also need to export the router. For example:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/bar", (req, res) => {
    // ...
});

module.exports = router;
```

Where the final route will be `"/foo/bar"`. For just `"/foo"`, you can define a handler for `"/"` within `foo.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You might have mistakenly used `app.get(router)` instead of `app.use(router)`.

Comment: Hi, this is an old question, and has an already accepted answer. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and welcome here in SO