# different between router in node js

Tags: node.js, express, post, get, router

what is difference between routing method in `express()` and in `router()` function in `express()`?

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const router=express.router();


//routing with express
app.get(/,(req,res)=>{
res.send('Get method with express');
});


//routing with router function in express
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
res.send('Get method with router in express')
});
```

which on for routing is better?
which one should i use?

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/28305120/3001761?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences between express.Router and app.get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305120/differences-between-express-router-and-app-get)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305120/differences-between-express-router-and-app-get