# how to solve 'TypeError: req.isAuthenticated is not a function' error?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, ejs, express-session

i am trying to create a website using nodejs, express, ejs, passportjs, express-session, etc. its a normal website but i am trying to give admin panel to add dynamic content on the website. i have given routes for admin panel. but i am getting this error when i try to get the /admin path or any path related to admin as well: TypeError: req.isAuthenticated is not a function. anyone knows how to solve it? below is my code:

app.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const ejsLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const cors = require('cors');
const webRoutes = require('./routes/webRoutes')
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes')

const app = express()

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(cors());

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(ejsLayouts);



// Middleware to set currentPage variable
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.currentPage = req.path;
    next();
});



app.use("/", webRoutes);
app.use("/admin", userRoutes);




const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

passport-config.js:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
  const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
    const user = getUserByEmail(email)
    if (user == null) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'No user with that email' })
    }

    try {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user)
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' })
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return done(e)
    }
  }

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, authenticateUser))
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id))
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    return done(null, getUserById(id))
  })
}

module.exports = initialize
```

userRoutes.js:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config()
}

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const passport = require('passport');
const flash = require('express-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');

const initializePassport = require('../passport-config')
initializePassport(
    passport, 
    email => users.find(user => user.email === email),
    id => users.find(user => user.id === id)
)

const users = []


 app.use(flash())
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))


// Middleware to set layout for all admin routes
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.layout = 'layout_admin'; // Specify the admin layout
    next();
});

router.get('/', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('./admin/admin_home', {name: req.body.name});
});

router.get('/login', checkNotAutenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('./admin/admin_login');
});

router.post('/login', checkNotAutenticated, passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: 'login',
    failureFlash: true
}) )

router.get('/register', checkNotAutenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('./admin/admin_register');
});

router.post('/register', checkNotAutenticated, async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
        users.push({
            id: Date.now().toString(),
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPass
        })

        res.redirect('login')
    } catch (err) {
        res.redirect('register')
    }
    console.log(users)
});

router.delete('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logOut()
    res.redirect('login')
})

function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next()
    }

    res.redirect('login')
}

function checkNotAutenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.redirect('/')
    }
    next()

}

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `userRoutes`, you're using both app and router, and passport is loaded in app, not router, so the router doesn't have passport middleware loaded, hence the error, because it's undefined.

So, in `userRoutes` just use `router` throughout instead of `app`, and load middleware in it:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
    
//...

router.use(flash())
router.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
router.use(passport.initialize())
router.use(passport.session())
router.use(methodOverride('_method'))

//...
```

router docs: [express.Router](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router)

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot man! appreciate your time.  one small question. i am beginner in this. will it make any difference if i use express() instead of express.Router() in my whole project for defining routes or i have to use express.Router() only if i have my routes in another module file?

Comment: you could, but there's difference, see details: [Differences between express.Router and app.get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305120/differences-between-express-router-and-app-get) in short, Router serves as a module which provides route related methods, while express() provides methods beyond that, for example, Router cannot listen etc., which is not needed on route level, so it's better to use Router, like said in the docs: [_You can think of it as a “mini-application,” capable only of performing middleware and routing functions_](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router)

Comment: hi. sorry to disturb you again. but as i was going on in my project. i have encountered another probelm. i have posted the question on stack overflow. it would be really helpful if you could help me this. i have a whole day but unable to figure out. this is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78131905/unable-to-fetch-data-from-body-in-ejs-web-application