# How do I import routes for testing with Supertest?

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, supertest

I have an application tested by Mocha and I'm able to successfully run my tests with what I have now, but I'm explicitly setting a `GET` route to `/api/v1` within my test file. Here's the test file...

`API.js`:

```
var request = require('supertest');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.get('/api/v1', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({
    "Hello": "World"
  });
});

describe('API', function () {
  it("Says 'Hello' is 'World'", function (done) {
    request(app)
      .get('/api/v1')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200, {
        Hello: 'World'
      }, done);
  });
});
```

Have you noticed how I say `app.get()` after the `require()` statements? I don't want to do that here. I want to be able to import my routes from the `routes` directory of my project.

I find it hard to believe that I'm supposed to duplicate all of these routes in my test file. How would I want to import the routes from the `routes` directory for use in this testing file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not required that the routes be imported into the test file. Once routes have been defined on the `express.Router` object, and the `app` uses the router, the `app` need only be exported from the main application file.

You'll define your routes in a separate file and export the router.
**routes.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Define routes
router.get('/api/v1', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({
    "Hello": "World"
  });
});

// Export the router. This will be used in the 'app.js' file.
```

**app.js**

```
//Import the router
var router = require('./routes');

// Use the router as middleware for the app. This enables the app to
// respond to requests defined by the router.
app.use('/', router);

// Export the app object
module.exports = app;
```

**app.spec.js**

```
// Import the app
var app = require('./app');

// Use the app object in your tests
describe('API', function () {
  it("Says 'Hello' is 'World'", function (done) {
    request(app)
      .get('/api/v1')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200, {
        Hello: 'World'
      }, done);
  });
});
```

`express.Router` helps organize your routes. The question is answered perfectly here: [What is the difference between "express.Router" and routing using "app.get"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607058/what-is-the-difference-between-express-router-and-routing-using-app-get?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: My routes (in the `routes` directory) are attached to `express.Router()`, so what's the difference between `app.get()` and `express.Router()`, and how could I get those routes out of `express.Router()`?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Basically I was using `var app = express()` instead of `var app = require('../app')`. Thank you for this!

Comment: Importing my v1 router causes the `You are trying to import` error