# How do I split up index.js file in a node/mean/express application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, refactoring

I've got one incredibly long index.js route file for my node/mongo/express application. Here is the structure.

```
app.js
/models
    Schedule.js
    Task.js
    etc...
/routes
    index.js
/public
    /javascript
    etc...
```

I want something like this

```
app.js
/models
    Schedule.js
    Task.js
    etc...
/routes
    index.js
    schedule.js
    tasks.js
    etc...
/public
    /javascript
    etc...
```

How can I split up my index.js file?

For example, I have tried to do something like this in my app.js file

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var tasks  = require('./routes/tasks');

// later in the file

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/tasks', tasks);
```

However, it is not finding my task routes like it did before when I had only the index.js. This is probably because I took all the routes starting with "/task" from my routes/index.js and placed them in routes/task.js, but why express not recognizing the routes in this new file?

Any advice at all would be helpful, my friend and I are very new to the whole meanjs way of doing things, and basically cobbled together what we have from various tutorials. Now we desperately need to refactor, because routes/index.js is getting too long to work with. I did my best to do what makes sense intuitively, could anyone out there give advice on how to break up our routes file?

Comment: var tasks  = require('./routes/tasks'); should have been var tasks  = require('./routes/task'). file name is different.

Comment: made a mistake posting here, I'll edit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include route handlers in multiple files in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059246/how-to-include-route-handlers-in-multiple-files-in-express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer to this question lies in how you import (require in this context) the router instance. Each one of those files should do a `module.exports` with a router object or something similar where the routes can be mounted on the app instance you create.

For example, have a look at how I do it (with yeoman's help that is) in a project I have on GitHub [here](https://github.com/alexkahn/jats/blob/master/config/express.js#L74), then refer to how the router object is exported for each route like [this](https://github.com/alexkahn/jats/blob/master/app/controllers/account.js#L8) example.

As another example of doing this, here is an open source project I've been contributing to [here](http://github.com/open-city/recycling). Notice that we have a slightly similar approach [here](https://github.com/open-city/recycling/blob/master/server.js#L51), then have a look at an example route declaration (with the corresponding export) [here](https://github.com/open-city/recycling/blob/master/routes/index.js#L110).

Comment: Ok. We tried to do it your way with using glob and I can see the merits of that approach. Unfortunately I think our code is too different than yours to immediately switch over like that. I'll be reading the documentation for express js today, mostly because I still don't know what the hell I am doing.  I appreciate the response and examples. I might not end up using your solution, but I'm sure it will help others, so I'll give you the accepted.