# How to use multiple router files

Tags: node.js, express

How do I use multiple router files using express framework?

In my app.js, I have the following code:

```
var controller = require('./controller/index');
var healthController = require('./controller/health/');

app.use('/', controller);
app.use('/health', healthController);
```

And controller/index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

And health.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET health confirmation. */
router.get('/health', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('OK');
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I hit the `http://localhost:8000/`, I get the correct page without any problem, however, `http://localhost:8000/health` results in 404 error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming the "health.js" resides in "controller" directory, may it be just a typo issue? ``var healthController = require('./controller/health/');`` has a trailing slash (/). Removing it would fly? So it becomes  ``var healthController = require('./controller/health');``

Comment: @tiblu Can you pls post this as an answer, so that I can accept it for your credit? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the "health.js" resides in "controller" directory, may it be just a typo issue? `var healthController = require('./controller/health/');` has a trailing slash (/). Removing it would fly? So it becomes `var healthController = require('./controller/health');`

Answer (score 2):

See [How to include route handlers in multiple files in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059246/how-to-include-route-handlers-in-multiple-files-in-express).

Export an anonymous function that can be "initiated" with a reference to the original express app.

**./controller/index.js**:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    /* GET home page. */
    app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('index');
    });
};
```

**./controller/health.js**:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    /* GET health confirmation. */
    app.get('/health', function(req, res, next) {
        res.send('OK');
    });
};
```

**./app.js**:

```
var app = require('express')();

var controller = require('./controller/index');
var healthController = require('./controller/health');

controller(app);
healthController(app);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your single node app must have single router object, a router object represents a server in express requiring unique port.
Hence you should create router object in you app.js passing it to all router files.

Code will be like -

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

var controller = require('./controller/index');
var healthController = require('./controller/health/');

controller(router);
healthController(router);
```

**index.js**

```
module.exports = function(router) {
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('index');
    });
}
```

**health.js**

```
module.exports = funtion(router) {
    router.get('/health', function(req, res, next) {
      res.send('OK');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in `health.js`:

```
router.get('/health', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('`OK`');
});
```

to

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('OK');
});
```

This will work fine check it out.