# Automatically requiring "controllers" from a folder in nodejs and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to include all files in a directory called "controllers" which has files with express routes and some other things in them.

The problem is that the routes defined inside those files are not working, but if I paste all the code in the index file(file requiring the controllers) they work just fine.

Here's my code/files:

**index.js**

```
// Expressjs
const app = require('express')();

// Load and initialize the controllers.
require('./lib/controllersLoader');

/*
 * Initializing the listener according to the settings in the config.
 */
app.listen(3000, err => {
    // Throwing an exception since the whole app depends on this.
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`SERVER: Running on port ${config.server.port}`);
});
```

**lib/controllersLoader.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Getting an Array of the files in the 'controllers' folder.
let files = fs.readdirSync( __dirname + '/../controllers');

files.forEach( fileName => {
    require( __dirname + '/../controllers/' + fileName );
});
```

**controllers/index.js**

```
const app = require('express')();
const debug = require('../config').debug;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello, World!');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your controller file, you are creating an express "subapp", attaching a route to it, and then doing nothing with it.

You should:

1. Pass your app as parameter in the require, and attach routes to your original express app
2. Return the subapp, or a router, and mount/use it from your main express app

**Example**:

**index.js**

```
// Expressjs
const app = require('express')();

// Load and initialize the controllers.
require('./lib/controllersLoader')(app);
```

**lib/controllersLoader.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Getting an Array of the files in the 'controllers' folder.
let files = fs.readdirSync( __dirname + '/../controllers');

module.exports = app => {
    files.forEach( fileName => {
        require( __dirname + '/../controllers/' + fileName )(app);
    });
}
```

**controllers/index.js**

```
const debug = require('../config').debug;

module.exports = app => {
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Hello, World!');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did, however, ill try to find a "cleaner" solution, if there is any...

Comment: Maybe  [express routers](http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#router) might help you make your controller files cleaner, the other files depends on your structure, you can change it as you wish! :)

Comment: Thanks, I used the routers, it's much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

I think you're initializing new express instances each time you're requiring it like this:

```
const app = require('express')();
```

Can you use only one express instance and pass it to your controllers ?
Something like so:

```
module.exports = function(app){

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Hello, World!');
    });
}
```

and to call them:

```
require( __dirname + '/../controllers/' + fileName )(app);
```

Your problem seems quite similar to this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6059938/734525