# NodeJS Express middleware goes to next one without next()

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to learn Express for NodeJS but I came across this:

I am trying to add 2 middlewares depeding on url, so on the /user to do something and on root to do something different. However the root middleware is always called even if i dont use `next()` and if i access the "/" url, the root middleware is called twice.

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();


app.use('/user', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('In user middleware ');
    res.send('<h1>Hello from User page</h1>');
});

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('In slash middleware !');
    res.send('<h1>Hello from Express !</h1>');
});

app.disable('etag');
app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be `get` or `post` not `use`

-`get` or `post` are routes

-`use` is middleware function

[check this](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

```
 const express = require('express');

  const app = express();


  app.get('/user', (req, res, next) => {
      console.log('In user middleware ');
      res.send('<h1>Hello from User page</h1>');
  });

  app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
      console.log('In slash middleware !');
      res.send('<h1>Hello from Express !</h1>');
  });

  app.disable('etag');
  app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I am following a video tutorial and somehow that code works for him but not for me?

Comment: So the tutorial is not a good one, this answer is good and simple, if you want a better example just check my answer on another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53138548/how-to-app-use-all-routes-from-different-file/53141493#53141493

Answer (score 1):

From an issue at GitHub.com

https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3260

> Hi @davidgatti my "root path middlware" I assume you are talking about
>   nr_one. If so, yes, of course it is executed on every request; app.use
>   is a prefix-match system. Every URL starts with /, so anything mounted
>   at / will of course get executed :)

Comment: You are the only one that actually answered my question without giving a different aproach. Thanks

Comment: It was a meaningful question that deserved a direct answer; cheers! Hope everything worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I can't confirm this but I suspect from the tutorial you are following you might be missing a line.

As you said, `app.use` is a middleware which will be added to all the route

So when you load say some **url** where you expect the middleware then it won't know about the request type (post, put, delete or get request).

Any alternate for this could be to try something like this

```
 app.use('/user', (req, res, next) => {
     if (req.method === 'GET') {
      console.log('In user middleware ');
      res.send('<h1>Hello from User page</h1>');
} 
  });
```

Again, Just check and compare his code thoroughly

Adding this link from [Justin's answer for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53138548/how-to-app-use-all-routes-from-different-file/53141493#53141493)

Answer (score -1):

In order to avoid such a problem, you have to use the `return` keyword.

When you send a file to the server, use `return`.

Try the following code,

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();


app.use('/user', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('In user middleware ');
    return res.send('<h1>Hello from User page</h1>');
});

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('In slash middleware !');
    return res.send('<h1>Hello from Express !</h1>');
});

app.disable('etag');
app.listen(3000);
```

At line 13 and 8, I used the return keyword.

So when you make `http://localhost:3000/` request, you will receive

> Hello from Express !

And whenever you make `http://localhost:3000/user` request, you will receive

> Hello from User page